# multiple operations in a single POST request -REST api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mean-stack, database-schema

Is there any way to handle multiple operations in a single POST request

```
app.post('/api/bus_routes',function(req,res){
    Route.find({
        $and:[{path:req.body.p1},{path:req.body.p2}]

    },function(err,bus_routes){
        //.......
    });
});
```

If first "and" doesn't give any results, Is it possible to call a "or" between them(p1 and p2) inside the same route?

Comment: cant you just check the output and make a call gain to find again and return the result.

Comment: yeah. That is what i am doing now.  But I wanted to know is there a way to handle it in a single request.

Comment: you mean single post request ?

Comment: yes.. what i want to know is that is it possible to gain both $and and $or results from a single post

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function provided by the *Route API* to check if you get desired data from the *And* query and if not make another call using the *or* query something like this.

```
   app.post('/api/bus_routes', function (request,res){
      Route.find(my _and_query, function (err,output){
        if(data.length){
          res.send(data);
        }else{
            Route.find(my_or_query, function (err,data){
             res.send(data);
       } 
        if(err){
           throw err;
          }
      }
    }
```

Please mind that this is pseudo code. Hope this helps .